# Simple function and tornado gen.engine

Tags: python, tornado

I am making a web application using Python + Tornado. Wrote a simple handler for example:

```
class AdminHandler(BaseHandler):

@tornado.web.authenticated
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@gen.engine
def get(self):
    response = yield gen.Task(self.acync_func_test, 'my')
    print response
    self.render('admin/index.html')


def acync_func_test(self, argument, callback):
    for i in xrange(1,59999000):
        i**2+2-12
    callback(argument)
```

But function is not performed asynchronously. Other clients are waiting until the query is executed for the first. How to make non-blocking execution?

**Update:**

Added  decorator '@gen.engine' to your async_func_test() function, but still blocked((

Answer (score 0):

Add decorator '@gen.engine' to your async_func_test() function